# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined when I am trying to access API call data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am trying to make a movie search app with React and have made an API call to The Movie Database API. I have this form and what I am trying to do is get the data of the movie that I am searching for.

I am not able to access the data from the API call, and I get this error of "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

I have two js files:
1 index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import SearchMovies from "./searchMovies";
import './style.css';

class Main extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h1 className="title">React Movie Search</h1>
        <SearchMovies/>
      </div>
  
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

The second file is searchMovies.js

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

export default function SearchMovies(){

//states- input query, movies
const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);

const searchMovies = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    const url = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/550? 
    api_key=api_key&language=en-US&query=${query}&page=1&
        include_adult=false`;

        try {
            const res = await fetch(url);
            const data  = await res.json();
            setMovies(data.results);
        }catch(err){
            console.error(err);
        }
}


return(
    <div>
        <form className="form" onSubmit={searchMovies}>
            <label htmlFor="query" className="Label">Movie Name</label>

            <input className="input" type="text" name="query" placeholder="i.e. Jurassic 
                Park"
                value={query} onChange={(e) => setQuery(e.target.value)}
            />

            <button className="button" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
        <div className="card-list">
            {movies.map(movie => (
                <div className="card">
                    <img className="card--image"
                        src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185_and_h278_bestv2/
                        ${movie.poster_path}`}
                        alt={movie.title + ' poster'}
                        />

                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
}
```

Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong here? I am new to React.
Many thanks!

Comment: Just check that is `data.results` an array because if it's not an array then the error will show.

Answer (score 1):

Your API response an object, not an array that's why the map function not working.

See Your API response:

{"adult":false,"backdrop_path":"/rr7E0NoGKxvbkb89eR1GwfoYjpA.jpg","belongs_to_collection":null,"budget":63000000,"genres":[{"id":18,"name":"Drama"}],"homepage":"http://www.foxmovies.com/movies/fight-club","id":550,"imdb_id":"tt0137523","original_language":"en","original_title":"Fight Club","overview":"A ticking-time-bomb insomniac and a slippery soap salesman channel primal male aggression into a shocking new form of therapy. Their concept catches on, with underground "fight clubs" forming in every town, until an eccentric gets in the way and ignites an out-of-control spiral toward oblivion.","popularity":46.801,"poster_path":"/pB8BM7pdSp6B6Ih7QZ4DrQ3PmJK.jpg","production_companies":[{"id":508,"logo_path":"/7PzJdsLGlR7oW4J0J5Xcd0pHGRg.png","name":"Regency Enterprises","origin_country":"US"},{"id":711,"logo_path":"/tEiIH5QesdheJmDAqQwvtN60727.png","name":"Fox 2000 Pictures","origin_country":"US"},{"id":20555,"logo_path":"/hD8yEGUBlHOcfHYbujp71vD8gZp.png","name":"Taurus Film","origin_country":"DE"},{"id":54051,"logo_path":null,"name":"Atman Entertainment","origin_country":""},{"id":54052,"logo_path":null,"name":"Knickerbocker Films","origin_country":"US"},{"id":25,"logo_path":"/qZCc1lty5FzX30aOCVRBLzaVmcp.png","name":"20th Century Fox","origin_country":"US"},{"id":4700,"logo_path":"/A32wmjrs9Psf4zw0uaixF0GXfxq.png","name":"The Linson Company","origin_country":""}],"production_countries":[{"iso_3166_1":"DE","name":"Germany"},{"iso_3166_1":"US","name":"United States of America"}],"release_date":"1999-10-15","revenue":100853753,"runtime":139,"spoken_languages":[{"iso_639_1":"en","name":"English"}],"status":"Released","tagline":"Mischief. Mayhem. Soap.","title":"Fight Club","video":false,"vote_average":8.4,"vote_count":20153}

Comment: And you have a solution?

Comment: Your actual API link below. This URL works properly.

`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=fedbe6a180fedfbf90f45a61bc8d62d0&language=en-US&query=${query}&page=1&include_adult=false`

Answer (score 1):

I made a jsfiddle with your code for testing: https://jsfiddle.net/hqm6rcpf/

```
const url = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/550? 
    api_key=api_key&language=en-US&query=${query}&page=1&
        include_adult=false`;
```

This code is invalid. You cannot add line breaks in a URL.

By changing to this, I was able to make it work:

```
const url = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=api_key&language=en-US&query=${query}&page=1&include_adult=false`;
```

Comment: I tried your code and it's not working, I have the same error.

Comment: I have no idea why my local project is not working, I added your code and I still have the same error...It's frustrating.

Comment: My bad, Xurei! I don't know what I was doing before, but now is working! Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

first of all,
never share your personal api key on the internet!!

```
 const data  = await res.json();
```

Why use await again when you have already fetched the data?
also, if the response is json, it's JSON.parse(res).

Next, have you actually looked at the data you are getting?
Try console logging it.
From what I can tell, it's an object, not an array, so you can't use map.

Comment: Hey Yannick you need to add await because `res.json()` will return a promise whereas `JSON.parse` wont return a promise thats why we dont need await

Comment: So, when I added this line of code in searchMovies.js " const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]); " was the first time when I had the error.

Comment: Well yes, because you set the movies state to your fetch request response, so if the response is not an array. The map function causes an error.
Try console logging your data variable before you run setMovies.

Comment: Yannick, I console logged it and you are right, is an object.